# Transferring information from a dataframe to another

Tags: r, dataframe

here is my problem. I have two dataframes, df1 and df2. I'd like to add a column named `issp` to df1 in function of values taken by a column named `sp` in df2. df1 and df2 have a column named `loc` in common but it is repeated a lot in df2 (~90k rows in df2 against 5k rows in df1).

The idea is to identify the locations in df1 which contain the specie sp by giving to the column issp the value 1.

Here is the script I use:

```
for (i in (1:length(df2$loc)) {
  if (df2[i, "sp"]==1) {
      df1(which[df1$loc==df2[i, "loc"]],)$issp = 1 
  }
}
```

It doesn't work and R sends me back the following error:

```
Error in `*tmp*`[df1[, "loc"] == df2[i, "loc"]] : 
  object of type 'closure' is not subsettable`
```

Comment: You `df1(which...)` is wrong. You used `(` instead of `[`. It must be `df1[which...]`.

Comment: Indeed... sorry for that and thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a syntax error:

```
df1(which[df1$loc==df2[i, "loc"]],)$issp = 1
```

Should be

```
df1[which(df1$loc==df2[i, "loc"]),]$issp = 1
```

Comment: ... Indeed, sorry for the useless question. And thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

A better way to do this

```
#Get indices of sp in df2 that are 1
df2.sp.idx <-which(df2$sp ==1)
df1$issp <-NA
df1$issp[which(df1$loc %in% df2$loc[df2.sp.idx])] <-1
```